# Setting range dynamically based on datapoints in ShinobiCharts

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, charts, shinobi

[image]

I'm using Shinobi Controls Charts to do this project and i'm having some trouble to find out how to set dymanically maximum range my Shinobi chart to look as close as possible to this:

`Set Maximum range dynamically`

SChartNumberRange *r;

r = [[SChartNumberRange alloc] initWithMinimum:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:@(-20.0)] andMaximum:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:@(120.0)]];

Any other option to set default Min & Max range dynamically.